# Trying to get meaningful timestamp while subtract it with actual time of Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

a=`date '+%H'`. when i do a-1, if the time is 00:00 it will give me -1 which is not i want. I trying to show it as 23:00.

Could you please help me with working code?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `if (( a < 0 )); then ((a + 24)); fi` ??

Comment: As i'm using solaris one, this will help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're doing the following to assign hour value to `a`:

```
a=`date +%H`
```

and you get value of `a` equal to 00, to subtract 1 hour do:

```
a_minus_1h=`date +%H -d "$a 1 hour ago"`
```

Comment: What will that -d do ?

Comment: `-d` (or `--date`) displays time described by string, not actual time. `man` is your friend, try `man date` ;)